# Chrome plugin local storage

Tags: google-chrome

i'm woundering where are chrome.local.storage files are located.

i tried to look at `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage`

but there are only html local.storage files and not chrome's plugin files

Comment: Local Extension Settings.

Comment: @JoshLee Can you be more spesific?